# Export Google BigQuery data to Python Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, google-bigquery

I've been researching how to export BigQuery data into Pandas. 
There are two methods:

1. Export the file to a CVS and load it - https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/exporting-data-from-bigquery
2. Directly pull the data into a pandas frame. This doesn't seem to work but here is the method - pandas.io.gbq.read_gbq(query, project_id=None, index_col=None, col_order=None, reauth=False) .
   It appears gbq has been discontinued?

Could someone please suggest the best and most efficient way to go about this?

Thank you.

Comment: What version of pandas are you using? It looks like it still exists in 0.15.0: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.gbq.read_gbq.html

Comment: Yes that's precisely what i'm using. Still no success. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I've developed a python package (with 100% test coverage): [google-pandas-load.readthedocs.io/en/latest](https://google-pandas-load.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) that follows the first method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `gbq.read_gbq` method definitely works in pandas .15.0-1 as I just upgraded from .14.0-1 to check (Windows 7). If you are using Python, I would definitely recommend this for getting data into a dataframe from Google BigQuery as it is something I use for almost all my analysis work.

It is hard to say how to overcome your issue without more information, but I would start with checking if the authentication flow is completing in your browser that is logged into your Google account and then troubleshoot from there.  There is a deprecation warning on your first authentication flow (oauth2client.tools.run), but everything does still work.

Other than that, I would try following the examples here: http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/io.html#io-bigquery

FYI, in the current dev branch, an option for Gcloud authentication is being added to make headless authentication more convenient.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the google cloud library and store it to dataframe

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
import os

#Your credentials to google cloud
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]=r"C:\YourPath\to\credentials.json"

# Construct a BigQuery client object.
client = bigquery.Client()

#Select Your table in BQ
query = """
    SELECT *
    FROM `bigquery-public-data.usa_names.usa_1910_2013`
"""
query_job = client.query(query)  # Make an API request

result = query_job.to_dataframe()  # Stores your query results to dataframe
```